Supervised classification ALOS-PALSAR Google Earth Engine
I need to create a supervised classification for flood detection with ALOS PALSAR in Google Earth Engine. How can I do this?

The Earth Engine Fundamentals and Applications book has an entire section on water application.
https://www.eefabook.org/table-of-contents.html
